# Datepicker in Angular Material (Angular 5)

Tags: angular

I Am Using Datepicker of Angular Material i want to add some basic custom css class to the datepicker and modify the existing classes of datepicker i had  added classes on google chrome developer tools and it reflects changes but when i add on my component css file it does not reflect changes.For Example i am using datepicker in RegisterComponent if i apply custom css class to datepicker in RegisterComponent.css file it does not reflect changes.Please Help me how can i acheive this to style my datepicker.I am using Angular 5.

Comment: There's a fairly complex guide to using 'Material' exactly by the guidelines, and even more complex guides for Angular specific solutions. If you just want to get the job done short term, chances are you just want to use the `!important` tag in your css definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Root Cause for this behaviour is because of ViewEncapsulation of angular component, By default all components will be of Emulated. In order to resolve this you can use following approaches depends on your requirement

- Change viewEncapsulation value to ViewEncapsultion.None in component metadata, in above case it will metadata of RegisterComponent, But drawback every global styles will bleed in to this components styles
- override the class in global style file instead of components style after basic setup of angular material is done such as theming, For Example if its angular cli project use global style.css scaffolded by angular cli

Answer (score 0):

Writing something similar according to your need in your component css file will do the trick.

```
 /deep/.mat-datepicker-toggle {
    background: url("/assets/icons/calendar.svg") no-repeat !important;
    position: absolute !important;
  }
```